# Excel: Disable 'Research' AND 'Online Services' on cell Alt+Click (programmatically)

Tags: excel, vba

I've searched and tested different ways to solve this to no avail.

---

On `Alt+LClick`, by default, a 'Research pane' pops up.
This can be disabled using the following:

```
Application.CommandBars("Research").Enabled = false
```

With 'Research' disabled though, `Alt+Click` *still* triggers some built in event causing a delay.
I'm not sure exactly what is Excel doing, but the delay can be removed by changing the following option:

> Options > Trust Center > Privacy Options > Uncheck: Let Office connect
>   to online services...

The problem is, that with this disabled, on every `Alt+Click`, Excel shows a popup:

> "Do you want to lef Office connect to online services... Yes/No"

- Yes re-enables the services, thus adding the delay, No just dismisses the window. It will show again on next `Alt+Click`.

This window triggers **before** `Worksheet_SelectionChange`, so there's no way (I can find) to disable it using `events` or `cancel`.

---

Would anyone have any lead on an alternative solution or is this not possible to change and I'll have to live with the delay?

Comment: I should add that the reason I'm asking is that I'm working with a wb that has complicated input, and uses `Alt` key as a modifier for certain actions (`Ctrl` and `Shift` are used for selection, other keys are already used or too inconvenient, as this one additional modifier key would be used very often.

Comment: I haven't tested this but when you mention 'Research' being disabled and still triggers some built in event - it could be some search services.  Try go to - Trust Center settings - Privacy Options - Research Options and uncheck all boxes and see if that helps

Comment: Thank you Alex, unfortunately that does not help either with services enabled (delay) or disabled (popup).

Comment: I don't have another alternative if you have to stick with Alt + click.  Also I assume your Excel version is 2010 or above

Comment: Sorry for the late response Alex. It is Office 2016. Thanks anyway for taking the time to look into it.